# создание формы в css с вложенным адаптивным контентом

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка, масштабирование

Есть: 4 ссылки с соответствующими иконками.
Нужно: расположить их в полупрозрачную форму, которая бы адаптировалась при масштабировании страницы под границы ссылок(т.е. чтобы ни текст не иконки не вылазили за пределы формы) 
Пробовал: css генераторы форм, различные ротации, совмещение прямоугольника и треугольника, псевдоэлемент ":after". Ничего не выходило так, чтобы было ровно. HELP
p.s. я новичок, пожалуйста, не плюйтесь кислотой ;) [image: пример]

```css
   .item{
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 12%;
    transform:  scaleY(-1);
}
.linkiconsize img{
    height: 50px;
}


/*ICON BG SHAPES */
.trapezoid {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    width: 50%;
    top: 12%;
    border-top: 0 solid;
    border-right: 35px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-bottom: 61px solid black; /* white required */
    border-left: 0 solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -o-text-overflow: clip;
    text-overflow: clip;
    -webkit-transform:  scaleY(-1);
    transform:  scaleY(-1);
}
```

```html
       
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <!-- bootstrap -->
        
            <div class="wrapperpos trapezoid">
             <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center item">
                    <div class="col-6 col-md-2">
        
                        <a href="#">
        
                            <div class="linkiconsize">
                                <img src="img/wdep.png"/>
                            </div>
        
                            <span class="">
                        Web development
                    </span>
        
                        </a>
        
                    </div><!-- web dev -->
        
                    <div class="col-6 col-md-2">
        
                        <a href="#">
        
                            <div class="linkiconsize">
                                <img src="img/app.png"/>
                            </div>
        
                            <span>
                        Mobile applications
                    </span>
        
                        </a>
        
                    </div><!--mobile applications-->
        
                    <div class="col-6 col-md-2">
        
                        <a href="#">
        
                            <div class="linkiconsize">
                                <img src="img/seng.png"/>
                            </div>
        
                            <span>
                        Service engineering
                    </span>
                        </a>
        
                    </div><!--service-->
        
                    <div class="col-6 col-md-2">
        
                        <a href="#">
        
                            <div class="linkiconsize">
                                <img src="img/bsn.png"/>
                            </div>
        
                            <span>Business analysis and audit</span>
                        </a>
        
                    </div><!--business-->
        
                </div><!-- row with no gutters + link's positions-->
                    </div><!--container -->
                    </div> <!--wrapper-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил через  `transform skew()`.
Добавил через `:after` к основному контейнеру и применил `skew()`.

Не совсем то, что я хотел изначально, конечно. Но неплохой рабочий вариант.
Еще есть вариант с `clip-path`, но он поддерживается не всеми браузерами.
(п.с. вся инфа, что выше от зарубежных коллег)

```css
 .item{
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 12%;
}/*all items INTO the shape*/

.posanddeco {
    margin-top: 1em;
}/*positioning in the shape */

 .wrapperpos {
        display: flex;
        margin: 10% auto auto 0;
        position: relative;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
        box-sizing: content-box;
        background: black;
        min-height: 10em;
        height: max-content;
        -o-text-overflow: clip;
        text-overflow: clip;
        opacity: 0.9;
        width: 70%;
    }
.wrapperpos:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 92%;
        width: 5em;
        height: 10em;
        background: black;
        transform: skew(-20deg);
        z-index: -1;

    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="wrapperpos">
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center item">
        <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 posanddeco">

            <a href="#"><img src="img/wdep.png"/><span class="nowrap">Web development</span></a>

        </div><!-- web dev -->

        <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 posanddeco">

            <a href="#"><img src="img/app.png"/><span class="nowrap">Mobile applications</span></a>

        </div><!--mobile applications-->

        <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 posanddeco">

            <a href="#"><img src="img/seng.png"/><span class="nowrap">Service engineering</span></a>

        </div><!--service-->

        <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 posanddeco">

            <a href="#"><img src="img/bsn.png"/><span class="nowrap">Business analysis and audit</span></a>

        </div><!--business-->


    </div><!-- row with no gutters + link's positions-->
        </div><!--container -->
        </div> <!--wrapper-->
```